# How to check for a certain word in string in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Hope you are doing well guys, I have a problem with batch file.

I have a batch file where user types a PC DNS, there is 4 numbers and 2 letters and again number or 2 numbers for example "1234ds2" or "1234cm02".

For now I have a code looking like this (I'm new at batch so sorry)

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
@chcp 1250

Cls
echo Please input the computer name that you want to reset the service:
set /p "salon= "
IF %salon%|findstr /i "ds" (echo "Resetting service for computer %salon% pause)
else (echo Resetting service for PC %salon% pause)
```

After doing some stuff in PsExec, I want program to pause and let user end the batch file, by clicking any key.

I wanted to do this by finding word "ds", if user inputs it this will go to first IF, resetting specific computer, else this program would reset other PC with "cm" in name. Now I wonder if it wouldn't be better to input 2 IF with "ds" and "cm".

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: That's not valid `if` syntax (and won't work that way at all). You can use conditional execution instead: `echo %salon%|findstr /i "ds" >nul && echo DS found || echo no DS found`

Comment: Thanks, so I changed it into GOTO function, so my code looks like this right now:

echo %salon%|findstr /i "ds" >nul && goto DSfound || goto noDSfound

but if I write in cmd "1234ds1" it goes to :DSfound and then goes to :noDSfound instead of stopping at :DSfound

Comment: There is no need at all to use `findstr.exe` for this task, you could just use your `If`/`Else` structure without it, and use variable expansion and replacement instead. ```If /I Not "%salon:ds=%" == "%salon%" (Echo Resetting service for computer %salon%& Pause) Else Echo Resetting service for PC %salon%& Pause```.

Comment: Hello @Compo, for now this script works perfectly, thank you very much!

Comment: A label does not stop the code. Use `goto :eof` before the label.